# Ember cli toggle sidebar "implementing the Jquery part?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ember.js

I am trying to implement a small toggle sitebar in my ember application. The bootstrap part is easy to implement. But I've got no clue how to implement the javascript part into a view.

Sidebar I want to use in my app: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/nav-sidebar-with-toggle-button

Could somebody tell me how to fix the jQuery part? (sidebar is active, but have to be inactive when visiting the website. Sitebar have to pop open at the moment the user clicks on the option button).

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
$(function(){

 $('#slide-submenu').on('click',function() {           
        $(this).closest('.list-group').fadeOut('slide',function(){
         $('.mini-submenu').fadeIn(); 
        });
        
      });

 $('.mini-submenu').on('click',function(){  
        $(this).next('.list-group').toggle('slide');
        $('.mini-submenu').hide();
 })
})
  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 sidebar">
    <div class="mini-submenu">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="list-group">
        <span href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            Submenu
            <span class="pull-right" id="slide-submenu">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            </span>
        </span>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> Lorem ipsum
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Lorem ipsum
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i> Lorem ipsum
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open-o"></i> Lorem ipsum <span class="badge">14</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Lorem ipsumr <span class="badge">14</span>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> Lorem ipsum
        </a>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Can you throw this into a jsbin?

Answer (score 1):

When implementing JS in a view, you want to put your code in the `didInsertElement` hook:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // Your code here
    }
});
```

See this jsbin for a working example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qegedehovo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Things you didn't have in your snippet that are in the jsbin:

- Font Awesome Icons
- CSS taken from the link you provided that styles the mini-submenu